# Line breaks in Microsoft planner description field - a bug or a feature?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-planner

I am using microsoft planner graph API to get data from Microsoft Planner. This all works good, but when I get the description field, I'm puzzled over its value. Am I missing something, or maybe there is just a new bug in planner API?

The `description` field in planner looks like this: total 5 lines, the second line is *empty*, the fourth line *has two spaces* (the one between "two" and "three"):

[image]

Now what I see in the description field when I call the planner API? This:

```
\r\nLine One\r\n\r\n  \r\n\r\n\r\nLine Two\r\n\r\n  \r\n\r\nLine Three\r\n
```

**How do I "decode" that string to a reasonable multi-line text?**

If I try to split that by `\r\n\r\n` (?) and trim, that does not work (i.e. the result is not what you see in the picture above). So I wonder how that string is built, if it is not a concatenation using `\r\n`? Note there is `\r\n\r\n\r\n` (six chars) sequence? May this whole thing be a planner bug? My memory may be fuzzy, but I think it worked differently a few months ago.

Also note, some whitespace chars in the string above are not spaces `\32` but non-breaking spaces `\160`